# 2017 Poly Bag - Blue and Black bricks

Tags: set-identification

I received a bag of Lego bricks without a box or identifying build number. The numbers on the bag are 135149 the year is 2017. The bricks are blue and black. I scanned the QR code and got the following number: 6172058.

I was not able to find any information on your site or even doing a search across many platforms of Lego enthusiasts.

[image: Blue and Black bricks only]

Answer (score 7):

based on

- 2x [PLATE 4X6](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-303223/) in blue
- set produced in or after 2017
- the other blue parts,
- lot of same color parts in 1 bag -> probably classic set with lot of standards bricks

this bag is from

[11011: Bricks and Animals](https://brickset.com/sets/11011-1/Bricks-and-Animals)

[image]

Comment: While set is identified correctly, the chosen part doesn't point to the one and only set. Combination of [Blue Arch 1 x 6 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=15254&colorID=7&in=A), which exist in just 3 sets, with other bits in Blue would have been a better choice.

Comment: When Joost says "in or after 2017", that's correct because the year (and all the other numbers) on the bag refer to the bag itself. so the bag was designed in 2017, and thus can't be used for sets produced before.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity trouble is that there are 14 sets with 2017-2018 release years alone for this particular element-color combination. And this packaging could be reused for other years moving forward. Thus making a range of possible sets quite large.

Comment: @Alex: I know, I just wanted to point out to the OP that there was a good reason for why this answer said "in or after".

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity : it's not always as simple as that - just because a set was first released in year X does not mean there can't be production runs of the set in later years. A set first released in 2015 might have a production run in 2017, and thus use bags designed in 2017. That said - this answer identifies the set correctly - no other sets produced at any time match the parts in the bag.